# Declaring array of strings with initialization values in Visual Basic (VB))

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I'd like to use VB.net to declare an array of 9 strings and give them some default values, but I'm getting an error with the following code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Code:
Dim myWords(9) As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"}

Error:
Explicit initialization is not permitted for arrays declared with explicit bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error if straight forward, don't declared the array with explicit bounds.

```
Dim myWords() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"}
```

As Tim said, you can even do

```
Dim myWords = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"}
```

Comment: or even  more concise: `Dim myWords = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"}`

Comment: Yes. But what if I want to make _sure_ that I gave just enough values for the size? Say months, weekdays, etc. To bad the compiler can't do that in one go.